# Linq with sum with nullable int

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to compute a sum of nullable int using Linq. My query looks like this:

```
int? surveysPromotersFromChatsGroup = (from surveyResult in surveyResultsFromChats
                                            where surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS.HasValue && surveyResult.GroupID == gr && surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS >= 9
                                            select surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS).Sum();
```

FirstScoreNPs field is a nullable int. My problem is that the sum always return null no matter what. I can't see the logic behind this. I checked and I know for certain that some entities do have values in that field and the sum method should sum up those values.

Another approach that I tried is like this:

```
int surveysPromotersFromChatsGroup = (from surveyResult in surveyResultsFromChats
                                      where surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS.HasValue && surveyResult.GroupID == gr && surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS >= 9
                                      select surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS).Sum(score => score.Value);
```

But I get an exception "linq the null value cannot be assigned to a member with type".

Isn't there a way to sum up the non null values from that field using linq?

The surveyResultsFromChat is actually from another query:

```
                var surveyResultsFromChats = from surveyResult in db.SurveyResults
                                    join survey in db.Surveys on surveyResult.SurveyID equals survey.SurveyID
                                    join userGroup in db.UserGroupMaps on surveyResult.UserID equals userGroup.UserID
                                    where surveyResult.CreatedDate >= startDate && surveyResult.CreatedDate <= endDate && surveyResult.UserID.HasValue && surveyResult.ChatSessionID.HasValue
                                    select new { surveyResult.ResultID, survey.BrandID, userGroup.GroupID, surveyResult.CompletedDate, surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS };
```

FirstScoreNPS in my model is an Nullable int.

Comment: consider using FirstScoreNPS.GetValueOrDefault() instead of 'FirstScoreNPS' in the 'select' part of your linq query

Comment: Which type of linq is it? Database? Entities?

Comment: I use Linq to sql. The field that causes that trouble is an int? which is a nullable int. I tried similar queries but without sum, just count and it works so I guess the sum method is the problem

Comment: I also have similar problem, and solve it with GetValueOrDefault() as written by @GlennFerrieLive .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try out

```
(from surveyResult in
 surveyResultsFromChats
where surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS.HasValue && surveyResult.GroupID == gr && 
surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS >= 9
   select surveyResult.FirstScoreNPS).
Select(score => score.Value ?? 0).Sum();
```

Comment: The `FirstScoreNPS.HasValue` in the `Where` should have blocked out all `null` values from `score`, so all `score.Value`s will be non-null.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - not sure about the model thats the problem over here